# SQL - what's the correct date format for julianday function?

Tags: sqlite

So i am trying to query a database and indicate the total hours each user was involved in counting in order to allow pay to be determined.I should provide the totals for that date, the week ending on that date and the preceding month ending on that date.

i have three queries but they are not returning anything:

```
SELECT username,SUM((julianday(end_time)-julianday(start_time))*24) as duration from Session where start_time<=DATE('2019-07-20','+1 day') AND start_time>=DATE('2019-07-20','0 day') GROUP BY username

SELECT username,SUM((julianday(end_time)-julianday(start_time))*24) as duration from Session where start_time<=DATE('2019-07-20','+1 day') AND start_time>=DATE('2019-07-20','-7 day') GROUP BY username

SELECT username,SUM((julianday(end_time)-julianday(start_time))*24) as duration from Session where start_time<=DATE('2019-07-20','+1 day') AND start_time>=DATE('2019-07-20','-30 day') GROUP BY username
```

The dates are valid and its already in the database. Anyone know whats going on?

Data in the database: 
[Dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Iumt.png)

```
+----------+----------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
| Username | Session_ID           | Start_time         | End_time           |
+----------+----------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
| test9    | X7kP0ARulnaWaiXG2WlH | 2019-7-20 08:54:00 | 2019-7-20 11:57:00 |
+----------+----------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
| test4    | piS6GWIzYUxsv8ibIJWP | 2019-7-20 08:51:00 | 2019-7-20 10:51:00 |
+----------+----------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
| test1    | MVYKrORQseOzhrYfXl3V | 2019-7-20 08:50:00 | 2019-7-20 11:42:00 |
+----------+----------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
| test5    | 6FjiFHK6PHD8_5gKqNPg | 2019-7-20 08:48:00 | 2019-7-20 11:53:00 |
+----------+----------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
| test3    | mdKL06e_5Zt9ISMyPQ3h | 2019-7-20 08:43:00 | 2019-7-20 10:55:00 |
+----------+----------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
| test6    | zIlMPQ8kHw094HJHy6zS | 2019-7-20 08:39:00 | 2019-7-20 12:31:00 |
+----------+----------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
| test2    | rouH_1jFFwdW0RSUP9Nf | 2019-7-20 08:35:00 | 2019-7-20 11:15:00 |
+----------+----------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
| test8    | v8EFrHNchNr156XaOmRk | 2019-7-20 08:23:00 | 2019-7-20 12:06:00 |
+----------+----------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
| test7    | 3rkN1fEx9S6yhx8HaIsX | 2019-7-20 08:19:00 | 2019-7-20 11:57:00 |
+----------+----------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
| test10   | yjslD9UydwMAr0OL-gJ- | 2019-7-20 08:05:00 | 2019-7-20 10:47:00 |
+----------+----------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
```

Expected Output:

[image]

Result: 
[image]

It has stopped working after adding more dataset into the database. Before it had about 26 rows and it was working:

[image: When it was working]

MAYBE THIS IS THE CAUSE?: 
Before my date and time format was different: eg - 2019-12-02 19:26:18
but now its like this: eg - 2019-6-1 08:44:00 (all seconds 00)

[[image: Database before and after][5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gnn7a.png)

Comment: Please provide some sample data and expected output. Without that it is hard to come out with the solution

Comment: i have uploaded pictures of them

Comment: this is not mysql, this is sqlite

Comment: yes sorry, i saw the tag and i clicked it :)

Comment: you cannot do operation on your date format, it should be `2019-07-20 08:54:00`, is your start_time, varchar()?

Comment: No: "start_time" DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

Comment: @Asis, try this one `SELECT date('2019-7-20 08:54:00')`, it will return null

Comment: what it weird is that, i have populated the database with another 500 rows, before that i used to have like 26 and it was working but now it wont return anything. So weird

Comment: i added a picture of it, not that it helps :(

Comment: Change the format of the dates and it will work: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hFSEmCA7BtNaqhAvsDLjPT/0

Comment: yes, thats what i thought. It worked. THANKSSSSS !!!!

Comment: @Asis don't accept an answer that proposes to keep the wrong format of the dates and manipulate it to get the results that you want. Your problem is clear: "wrong format"  and the solution is also clear: "change to the correct format". Anything else will cause problems.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your end_time and start_time in one-time zone,
and difference in start time and end time in seconds, you can do like this.

```
select username, sum(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, start_time, end_time)) as duration 
from Session 
where start_time between date('2019-07-20') and date_add('2019-07-20', interval 1 day) 
group by username;
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that your issue is that the dates are not in a recognised format and thus that they will result in null values when using the julianday function. That is the month value is a single digit when less than 10, rather than being padded with 0 so instead of 2019-7-20, the data should be 2019-07-20 for use by the julianday function.

I believe that the following will produce the correct results for the first query :-

```
WITH cte(username, session_id, start_time,end_time) AS 
    (
        /* All this to convert dates to the correct format */
        SELECT 
          username, session_id,
            substr(start_time,1,5)|| CASE WHEN substr(start_time,7,1) =  '-' THEN '0'||substr(start_time,6) ELSE substr(start_time,6) END AS start_time,
            substr(end_time,1,5)|| CASE WHEN substr(end_time,7,1) = '-' THEN '0'||substr(end_time,6) ELSE substr(end_time,6) END AS endtime
        FROM Session
    )
SELECT 
    username,
    SUM((julianday(end_time)-julianday(start_time))*24) AS duration 
FROM cte /*<<<<< Use the CTE with the modified dates */
WHERE start_time<=DATE('2019-07-20','+1 days') 
    AND start_time>=DATE('2019-07-20','0 days') 
GROUP BY username
;
```

Of course the better solution would be to store the datetimes in a recognised format, which case the original query would work without the need for manipulation of the dates. Although the given solution works irrespective.

Comment: There is no difference between *day* and *days*: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/w3eJSf7ZpsMwuzWpPrPrrx/1

Comment: Great, now that you removed the 2nd (alleged) issue, will you also remove the proposal to keep the current date format and use tricks to manipulate the dates? The OP's problem is solved by by changing the format of the dates to the proper one.

Answer (score 0):

So i figured out a different way to tackle this problem:

The Datatype set in database was DATETIME and the python script i used to insert was inserting dataset from a csv file which was missing leading 0's. Now MikeT's answer above works because manipulation of the dates but it only worked for first query and i had to come up with a different way so that i could avoid this in the future.

forpas's way of changing the format of the dates as he demonstreated here https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hFSEmCA7BtNaqhAvsDLjPT/0 , to 'TEXT' also works but again the dataset has to be have the leading 0's.

So here is my solution to this if it helps anyone in the future:

i edited the python code to take in leading 0's using datetime library, with datetime library i could covert the date string from row.

This was possible because i posted another question on stackoverflow. Here is the link to that: [Inserting date correctly into SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59267647/inserting-date-correctly-into-sql/59268560#59268560)

thanks to Rithin Chalumuri, who found me this solution.

Also:

Big thanks to @forpas for the intial solution which helped me identified what the problem was.

Big thanks to @MikeT for providing me another way to solve this problem without changing the date type manually with manipulation of dates.

Big thanks to @Rithin Chalumuri, who provided me the solution to the problem with my python code in inserting 0's when it was missing, inserting from the dataset to the database.