# Inserting date correctly into SQL

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

I have Python code like this:

```py
with open('task9_in.csv', 'r') as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file, delimiter = ',')
    for row in reader:
        all_data.append(row)
```

The data structure in the csv file is like this:

```
test1 1/6/2019 1243 login
```

However when I run the code, the data is inserted into the database like this:

```
test1 2019/6/1 1243 login
```

The `0` is not being padded in. I want the expected date as

```
test1 2019/06/01 1243 login
```

How can i insert into the database with `0`.

This is the table definition:

[image]

Comment: What is the datatype of the date column field in sqlite?

Comment: What I expect is happening here is some implicit conversion to `datetime` format (and `0` is ignored because of that).

Probably in your db you also want data in database datetime format - can you show me your database definition (as Gideon already wrote too)?

Comment: i have uploded the table definition now

Comment: SQLite [has no date type](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#date_and_time_datatype). It can treat text in the ISO8601 format as dates though, ie `2019-12-10`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that the CSV file looks like this:

```
test1, 1/6/2019, 1243, login
```

You are missing the padding for date in your CSV file itself.
So, you can covert the date string from your row using datetime library.

This library is flexible enough to support multiple formatting. More info here (https://thispointer.com/python-how-to-convert-datetime-object-to-string-using-datetime-strftime/)

Try this:

```py
import datetime

before_string = '1/6/2019'

date = list(map(int, before_string.split('/'))

date_obj = datetime.date(date[2], date[1], date[0])

padded_string = date_obj.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')

print(padded_string)
```

Outputs:

```
01/06/2019
```

Now this can then be inserted into your SQL table.